# Where can I find the Wizard's Virge in Legend of Grimrock 2?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock-2

A **Wizard's Virge** is listed in the [Weapon - Wand/Orb/Staff](http://legendofgrimrock.com/index.php?id=116&site=2) section of a Legend of Grimrock 2 web site.

Where can I find this staff?

[image: Wizard's Virge]

Comment: The first google result points to the wiki that answers this https://grimrock.fandom.com/wiki/Wizard%27s_Virge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wizard's Virge is a staff dropped by the Island Master after his defeat in the Trickster's Lair.